# Interoperability between Goodreader and Acrobat

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I use Acrobat on iMac and Goodreader on iPad. It is fairly interoperable: for example, I can start an annotation on one and continue on the other. Unfortunately, this is not possible for the Outline (Goodreader term) a.k.a. Bookmark (Acrobat term). One issue is that outlines  are not editable in Goodreader. Any workaround one can think of? Thanks and regards

Comment: There are far more capable PDF viewers for iPad than GoodReader. I suggest you use one of those.

Comment: @KJ thanks I shall have a look

Comment: @joelgeraci Thanks for your answer. Can you suggest an editor on iPad that offers interoperability on Acrobat’s bookmark function? Thanks and regards

Comment: I just use Adobe Reader on iOS but there are others.

Comment: I did not know that one can create, modify and suppress bookmarks in Adobe Reader. It would be great indeed.